# Why the method printInfo does not see the fields of the structure?

Tags: go, oop, struct

I want recieve Word: go Page 8 Num of pages 34, but have:
Number of words:
1
Enter word:
go
Enter page:
8
Enter num of pages:
34
Word:
Page: 0
Num of pages: 0

Process finished with the exit code 0
How can I fix it?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Word struct {
word            string
page, numOfPage int
}

func (obj *Word) printInfo() {
fmt.Printf("Word: %v\n", obj.word)
fmt.Printf("Page: %v\n", obj.page)
fmt.Printf("Num of pages: %v\n", obj.numOfPage)
}

func inputInfo(obj *Word) {
var (
    word            string
    page, numOfPage int
)
fmt.Println("Enter word: ")
fmt.Scan(&word)
fmt.Println("Enter page: ")
fmt.Scan(&page)
fmt.Println("Enter num of pages: ")
fmt.Scan(&numOfPage)
obj.page = page
obj.word = word
obj.numOfPage = numOfPage
}

func main() {
var n int
fmt.Println("Number of words: ")
fmt.Scan(&n)
slc := make([]Word, n)
for _, elem := range slc {
    inputInfo(&elem)
}
for _, elem := range slc {
    elem.printInfo()
}
}
```

Comment: `printInfo` "sees" the fields, or this wouldn't compile. You are writing the changes to a copy of each `[]Word` element.

Comment: Why do i write to a copy? I use &elem and an argument in a funciton is pointer.

Comment: `elem` is a copy of the value in the slice.

Comment: Everything, I understand, use slc[i] instead of elem. Thanks a lot!